# Google Search Console index urls of an unknown website

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, search-engine-indexing, google-index, yoast

I have got a problem with Google Search Console indexing. When I try to search for `site:mywebsite.com` I can see in Google results titles and descriptions of a website that doesn't have completely anything common with my website. It refers to a different website.

Website runs on Wordpress. I have checked both .htaccess and all FTP files looking for any redirection but with no results. Everything seems ok..

The only common thing of these websites is IP address of webhosting provider `79.170.251.40`

As you can see in the picture below the links refers to my site which is correct. But titles and descriptions come from the other website.

[image]

This show me Wordpress Yoast SEO plugin in "Search Appearance" tab.

[image]

It's very tricky and to be honest I have no idea how to solve this issue. Do anyone has any idea how to fix?

Comment: does your site is hacked?

Comment: I used Wordfence to scan website and manually checked FTP and everything seems ok. Didn't find any signs of malware or anything what wouldn't be there. Do you think there can be a problem with my hosting provider and hosting settings?

Comment: This is almost always because of a hacked site.   Hacks often cloak so that they only give the hacked content to Googlebot.   You need to use inspect URL in Google search console to see the problems.

Answer (score 1):

I placed that /cenik URL into the Mobile Friendly Testing Tool and it looks like your site returned the home page. Unlike the 404 I see if I directly look at the page.

I checked the cache: for the page and it returns the page from that other site. That indicates that Google decided to canonicalise that page with the one on the other site.

On the Google Search Console do a URL Inspection on that page and share what it returns. Does it indicate the canonicalisation I see?

Click "VIEW CRAWLED PAGE" if it is available and check the "MORE INFO". Does it indicate the returned status code.

Do a Live Test and see if it also looks like the home page with a 200 status code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked this URL in GSC and it shows me the following https://prnt.sc/rwonkb

Comment: And also I can see this https://prnt.sc/rwopom. All the wrong URLs.

Comment: It's indicating the canonical is on that other domain, confirming that issue.Can you do a live test then view tested page, then more info.

Comment: There is a result of /cenik page live test. 1) https://prnt.sc/s0b0ig, 2) https://prnt.sc/s0b0tl. It still index page /cenik with wrong title & description even if the page doesn't exist (404) https://prnt.sc/s0b1ix

Comment: I'm now seeing 404s when I test as well. Once Googlebot re-crawls those pages it should remove them from the index.